# Extract zip file to HDFS using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, zip4j

I'm using Java-Spark, I'm get message from Kafka topic that indicate on zip file path, I want to take this zip file and to extract it to HDFS.

I have code that read messages from Kafka with Spark Structured Stream.

What is the way to extract the files to HDFS?

I'm using `ZipFile` from `net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile` as follow:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(pathFromKafka);
zipFile.extractAll("?");//What should I write here?
```

Answer (score 0):

ZipFile doesn't allow you to extract files to the HDFS
You can extract files to the local file system and then put these file into HDFS:

```
//imports required 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

//some class here .....
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", <hdfs write endpoint>);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(<src>, <dst>);
```